# substitute a value in one record with a value in another record based on a value comparison across the records

Tags: sql-server

Generally, I want to substitute a value in one record with a value in another record based on a value comparison across the records.

More specifically, I want to assign a `name` value to the records with `no name` in the name field below. To do this, I created `pct` and `allo_pct`. Starting with the lowest value in `allo_pct` I want to allocate the corresponding `name` value in a `no name` record when `pct <= allo_pct`, the proceed to the next higher value in `allo_pct` and do the same, until all `no name` records are assigned a `name` value with a `name`.

`pct` is a random value given to the records with `no name` values in the `name` field. `allo_pct` is the inverse of the percentage of `no name` records that I want to allocate with that name. All of this is done within groupings of `reg`, `type`, and `sub_type`. So within each `reg`, `type`, and `sub_type` grouping I will do this comparison and assignment.

For example say I start with this data (of course in my real data `reg`, `type`, and `sub_type` change across records not seen here):

```
reg type    SUB_TYPE    name        pct      allo_pct
c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
c   fr      nr           l         NULL     NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.31    NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.63    NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.05    NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.58    NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.28    NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.62    NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.84    NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.71    NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.7     NULL
c   fr      nr           no name    0.5     NULL
c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
c   fr      nr           s          NULL    0.706519623
c   fr      nr           s          NULL    0.706519623
c   fr      nr           s          NULL    0.706519623
c   fr      nr           s          NULL    0.706519623
```

I would expect to get something like this as a result:

```
  reg   type    SUB_TYPE    name        pct      allo_pct
    c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
    c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
    c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
    c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
    c   fr      nr           c         NULL     0.65040168
    c   fr      nr           l         NULL     NULL
    c   fr      nr           c          0.31    NULL
    c   fr      nr           c          0.63    NULL
    c   fr      nr           c          0.05    NULL
    c   fr      nr           c          0.58    NULL
    c   fr      nr           c          0.28    NULL
    c   fr      nr           c          0.62    NULL
    c   fr      nr           q          0.84    NULL
    c   fr      nr           q          0.71    NULL
    c   fr      nr           s          0.7     NULL
    c   fr      nr           c          0.5     NULL
    c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
    c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
    c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
    c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
    c   fr      nr           q          NULL    0.959993677
    c   fr      nr           s          NULL    0.706519623
    c   fr      nr           s          NULL    0.706519623
    c   fr      nr           s          NULL    0.706519623
    c   fr      nr           s          NULL    0.706519623
```

So in the above, if I did it correctly manually, on average about 65% of `no name` records should be assigned the name `c`, about 29% of the `no name` records should be assigned the name `s`, and about 4% of the `no name` records should be assigned. Note, its not exact because the `pct` value is randomly assigned, but over larger data sets it should work pretty well (suggestions welcome on this part but that is not my focus in the question).

Here is my first attempt at assigning `name`s like I describe above. It doesn't work:

```
select
    a.*
    ,case
        when b.pct <= a.allo_pct then a.name
        else b.name
    end name_modeled
from    
    cte_allo_pct b
    join cte_allo_pct a
    on b.REG = a.REG
    and b.TYPE = a.TYPE
    and b.SUB_TYPE = a.SUB_TYPE
where
    b.name <> 'NO name'
    and a.name = 'NO name'
```

I'm currently working this. I'll post other tries as I write them.

EDIT 1: This is my original question, but I have progressed from there I hope:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714621/assign-value-randomly-but-within-distributions-within-grouping

Comment: Please don't cross post the same question - you haven't even had the first one open for 24 hours yet and were getting help there. I'd suggest waiting it out to see what comes of it.

Comment: @LowlyDBA - i thought it was enough of a different question now that I could post something different.